# Local variable acessible outside block

Tags: ruby, scope

I am reading about ruby scopes, and it says that local variables aren't accessible outside the block they are defined in.

For instance, in the example below. `b` shouldn't be accessible outside the `if` block

```rb
a = 3
    while a<10 do
        if a<5
            b= 3
        end
        a+=1
    end
puts b
```

But for some reason,  I can access the `b` outside the block it was defined in

Comment: `for`, `while` and `until` loops do not create a new scope. Local variables defined before the loop are available within the loop and then after the loop. As you found, local variables created in the loop are also visible after the loop. This differs from methods that have blocks such as `each` and `loop`.  For those, local variables defined before are still visible in and then after the block, but the visibility of local variables created within the block is confined to the block. For example, `a = 5; loop do; a = a + 6; b = 3; break; end; a
 #=> 11; b #=> NameError (...)`.

Comment: There is no block in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ruby, a "block" is basically code that is enclosed either inside a `do...end` or between curly braces. (There are other ways — sort of — to create blocks in Ruby, but this definition will hold you for quite a while.) `if...end` isn't considered a block. Neither is `while...end`. To further complicate the issue, the `do` that you add after the `while` doesn't make it a block, either; Ruby just helpfully ignores it.

Cary has already explained this in the comments, but I'll see if I can clarify it a bit for you. I'll simplify and clean up your code a bit:

```
a = 3
while a < 10
  b = a * 3 
  a += 1
end
puts b
```

This will give 27. But now, if I do this:

```
a = 3
loop do
  b = a * 3
  a += 1
  break if a == 10
end
puts b
```

I'll get this:

```
undefined local variable or method `b' for main:Object (NameError)
```

which is what you were expecting. This is because `while` is a statement. `while...end` may enclose several lines of code, but it doesn't count as a block. (Ditto for `if`.) But `loop` is actually a method that takes a block as an argument, so the scoping rules that Cary describes in his comment apply.

Comment: OP most likely comes from an language where you have to explicitly loop using an index. You could use `(3...10).each do |a| <code> end` to get the same result. Or if OP uses it to access an array of some sort you cold `array.slice(3...10).each do |item| <code> end` Note that I use triple dots which exudes the end of the range.

Comment: I actually thought that anything within a ```do-end``` is a block. I had no idea that ruby ignores the do for ```while```

Comment: @VedantShetty Some [Keywords](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/keywords_rdoc.html) also use `end` to denote the end of what the doc calls a "syntax block." A block that is part of a method has the scoping rules under discussion here. A block that is part of a control expression such as `while` or `if` does not. Adding the `do` in this case doesn't change that.